# Custom views to view rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel Spreadsheet (Excel 2010 version) with lots of data. There are around 20 columns and thousands of rows.
Now the column widths are big so the columns don't fit on the screen and I have to scroll right to see the additional columns.

Is there a way that I can design a custom view where some columns can be on the top and some on the middle and bottom of the visible screen, so I can see all the data without scrolling?

I know Excel has a built in Form which helps to view, add , edit data but if there are many columns then we have to scroll down, right?
Also in the standard Form the columns are given one below the other- we cannot 'place' then in a customised position e.g. place *last name* to the right side of *first name* ?

[image: Screenshot of my requirements]